# Why does a manually deleted dhcpd lease return?

Tags: isc-dhcp

DHCPD: 4.3.6

OS: CentOS 8

I removed an entry from the dhcpd.leases file by using Webmin. It seemed to work for a time, but then the entry popped back into the file. Thinking it was a Webmin issue I then went back and did the following:
1. Stopped dhcpd
2. Opened up the dhcpd.leases file in vi and deleted the entry
3. Started dhcpd
When I grepped the dhcpd.leases file for that entry immediately afterwards I found it.

As far as I can tell no client is getting handed that lease: in checking the dhcp logs there is no reference to the deleted lease address for the time period. The lease entry still has the same Option 82 information and the same start/stop time so I am pretty certain that dhcpd is repopulating it on its own and not in response to a lease request.

How could this be happening? How can I work around it?

Comment: `As far as I can tell no client is getting handed that lease` - The lease should have a MAC address associated with it, yes?

Comment: @joeqwerty There is, but it is the MAC address of a device that is not connected to the network. I am confident that it did not send a DHCP request after I deleted the entry out of the dhcpd.leases file.

Comment: each lease for an ip which is free can be requested as long it is not blocked